# add_menu_page need help as it should work

Tags: php, wordpress

Since a week ago as an amateur at making my own custom plugins I wanted to make a settings page for my plugin.
After using some examples that should work on wordpress I am not having much success.
A sub page works just fine but I want it to be a top level menu the only reason I can think of why this is not working is because of some access rights issue? (happend before).

So if someone could help me with this would be nice.
Thanks in advance

I am not sure if I may link other sites/sources but here I go

The link below has the working example of a sub page
https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-settings-options-page-for-wordpress-plugin/

As for the other example I am working with that should work just fine is this
https://wpshout.com/wordpress-options-page/

```
<?php


add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'Counter_Opties_pagina_aanmaken');

function Counter_Opties_pagina_aanmaken(){
    $page_title = 'Counter';
    $menu_title = 'Counter Opties';
    $capability = 'edit_posts';
    $menu_slug  = 'Counter_pagina';
    $function   = 'Counter_pagina_inhoud';


    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );

}

function Counter_pagina_inhoud(){

    include 'Counter-Opties-file.php';

    }
```

This should generate at least the 'Counter Opties' in the sidebar of wordpress backend.

Comment: if my latest answer is not working add the following to your wp-config.php and paste the contents of the error log: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

Comment: Thanks for the help if after fixes in the code it still does not work I will try this was looking for such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I can see the issue is as follows:

- The slug isn't alphanumeric or all lowercase

The function MUST be located in the root of the plugin in your "initiator" file which should have the same name as your plugin folder. [See more here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Plugin_Files).

**Notes:**

- I would use manage_options over edit_pages for the capability
- I would use require_once instead of includes

More info on menu page function can be [found here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/).

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'Counter_Opties_pagina_aanmaken');

function Counter_Opties_pagina_aanmaken(){
    $page_title = 'Counter';
    $menu_title = 'Counter Opties';
    $capability = 'manage_options';
    $menu_slug  = 'counter-opties-file.php';
    $function   = 'Counter_pagina_inhoud';

    add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
}

function Counter_pagina_inhoud(){
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'counter-opties-file.php';
}
```

[image: As you can see it's added it succesfully]

Comment: Thank you I will try this out.

manage_options I am familiar with will replace it, but shouldn't my code at least show up in the side bar thats whats bugging me the most.
As the include is not that important as the first step is not working at all.

Comment: Have you swapped the menu slug? as it must all be lower case and alphanumeric? I've tried this code and it adds it the bottom of the sidebar navigation as expected.

Comment: Thank for the effort will take my time understanding this part will respond if I succeed.
I will also try to refrain from using uppercase letters as I did that on purpose not out of habit.

Comment: One thing that's missing is this: Where is OP's code located? And is OP confident the code is firing?

Comment: @cale_b good shout, that's why I just added for them to enable the debugging and logging as it will show any errors of such :)